# unable to create table with MEMORY engine on Amazon Aurora

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, amazon-aurora

Using the example from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engine-setting.html I do the following on my AWS Aurora server:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

The response I get back is as follows:

```
0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1266 Using storage engine InnoDB for table 't3';
```

Why isn't the MEMORY engine being used? According to `SHOW ENGINES;` it's supported...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186989/2703 includes this statement which is reported to be from AWS support:

> Aurora is designed to provide support for only InnoDB storage engine for regular tables. Engines other than InnoDB are only supported for session-level temporary tables. With default configuration, when you try to create a table using a storage engine other than InnoDB, Aurora will implicitly create the table as InnoDB. Session level temporary tables are not persistent and they will be dropped once the session is completed.

Comment: So I guess only `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` would use `MEMORY` as an engine?

Comment: That's how I interpret the above statement. Go ahead and try it! I don't have an Aurora instance spun up at the moment.

Comment: Yah - that's how it seems to work altho you still have to explicitly specify `MEMORY` as the engine. If you don't it'll still default to InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Aurora is converting myisam and memory tables to innodb.

```
mysql> create table mem_tbl( a int(11) ) engine=memory;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                         |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1266 | Using storage engine InnoDB for table 'mem_tbl' |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table mem_tbl \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mem_tbl
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mem_tbl` (
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As Aurora does disk based replication and automatic failover happens if current writer fails, Memory tables wont be safe. I am assuming it was decision made with these features in mind